# regex how to: if something is at beginning of the line the match is on then don't match

Tags: regex

I actually want to skip matches on lines that begin with "..." in this case.
I already have: `[^0]\\swarnings?(?!\\.|\\w)`  so I need to keep that functionality and add the don't match warning on lines starting with "..."
Thanks!
edit:  I'm using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a language supporting infinitely sized lookbehinds (like .NET), you can use

```
(?<!^\.\.\..*)yourterm
```

If you cannot use this, but know that there may be only one match of your expression per line, you could find those by using

```
^(?!\.\.\.).*(yourterm)
```

This will actually match the whole start of the line, but have the term you are interested in in a capturing group.

If you can have multiple matches per line, you can not easily achieve this with only one regex, I think.

In any case, it might be easier to use `^(?!\.\.\.).*` to first get rid of all lines starting with ... and start another run on these to obtain your matches.

Comment: Although many *implementations* of various languages may impose a limit on the size of a look-behind, I doubt that any language itself imposes such a limit.

Comment: +1 - thats +0.3 for the regex approach itself and +0.7 for the sane/pragmatic suggestion in the last paragraph ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^(?!\.+).+$
```

or, if you need to match 3 dots exactly,

```
^(?!\.{3}).+$
```

Edited to show case with OP's current regex:

```
^(?!\.{3})[^0]\\swarnings?(?!\\.|\\w)$
```

Comment: Provided the language supports negative lookahead.  (e.g. GNU grep doesn't http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2002/06/regexp.html)

Comment: hmmm, how does that fit with my existing: `[^0]\\swarnings?(?!\\.|\\w)`

Comment: @Stephen: True. OP didn't specify language.

Comment: that does not seem to work (I took out my extra backslashes, sorry about that).  No love though.

Comment: @Robusto: This (i.e. your sample #3) does not work because it does not allow characters between the start-of-line condition and the actual match.